# Memory Leak in iPad and iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to ask that how much MB of memory leak is tolerated by Apple for iPad and iPhone App. So that App is not rejected by App Store.
I have used Instruments in XCode to check memory leaks of my iPad Application. It leaks about 11 MB of memory. But when installed on iPad, App is not terminated by Springboard and runs continuously without any problem or error. I have released memory when object is of no use but still it leaks.

Answer (score 3):

Apple don't specify a limit for leaks, but I'd suggest that 11MB is huge. I aim to leak 0 bytes on every app I write. The fact that you're leaking that much implies that you don't understand memory management, so you should read carefully Apple's documentation on the subject:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i

or Google for some online tutorials that may be simpler for the beginner to understand. E.g.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2657/memory-management-in-objective-c-tutorial

The more memory your application uses, the more chance of it being killed, and the worse the user experience. Your app may run continuously now, but for how long?

Answer (score 0):

There is no amount specified as of toleration to memory leaks. The thing is that you shouldn't tolerate it yourself it is not good for the application nor for the performance and makes the application less stable. I advise you solving those memory leaks first, it will make the application of a better quality and satisfy your clients.

Answer (score 0):

I second the notion that there is no hard-set specified limit as such for memory consumption or memory leaks. This will depend I assume on the current memory consumption of the device at that particular time as well.

In any case, the method `- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application` will be fired anytime memory warning are received and you should probably listen into this method to try and free up some memory on your app. This warming will be sent a few times to the app, and if nothing is done to free memory up, the OS will forcibly quit the app (i.e it will crash out).

You can also try the `Build and Analyze` option in XCode to get a look at some potential memory leaks in your code.

Comment: I have used instruments (Build and Analyze) to check memory leaks. And have deployed App on iPad but it does not Crash in any case if it is constantly running for many days. Thanks for your guidelines i will follow the mentioned links to study memory management